# How to loop in MasonryList on React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, react-native, mapping

I want to use MasonryList component in my react native project.

So i created a component like this below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Image, StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity, Alert} from 'react-native';
import MasonryList from 'react-native-masonry-list';
import {books} from '../assets';

class Books extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MasonryList source={[{
          uri: '...'
        }]} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

so, "uri" prop expects a link for a single image, if you want to use multiple images you should have a structure like this.

```
{ uri: "link" }, {uri: "link2"}, {uri: "link3" }
```

and so on...

I have imported the books,  so  my question is how can i loop in the components itself, to reach each element's "thumbnail"  to get the url on the structure below?

my books.js file structure is like:

```
export default {
       items: [
          {
           kind: "books#volume",
           id: "md5"
           volumeInfo: {
                   imageLinks: {
                          thumbnail: "
```

Simply i could do mapping in the render function and create MasonryList component but that would create the component as much as the loop counts. I want only 1 component and multiple uri links in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a state array in "source" prop and in componentDidMount or at any relevant location, set this state using map function.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Image, StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity, Alert} from 'react-native';
import MasonryList from 'react-native-masonry-list';
import {books} from '../assets';

class Books extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
         imageArray: [],
         }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
      var imageArray = [];
       books.map(book =>{
        imageArray.push({uri: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail})
      });
    this.setState({imageArray});
       }
  render() {
    const {imageArray} = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <MasonryList source={imageArray} />
     </View>
   );
  }
 }
```